# How can I get rid of this phantom icon in Windows 10 explorer?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

A dummy icon has appeared in my *Devices and drives* section in Windows 10 explorer - shown selected here:

[image]

As you can see, when it's selected the *Properties* and *Rename* actions in the ribbon are inactive, and the *Drive Tools* ribbon section is hidden. If I right-click it I get a context menu containing *Cut*, *Create shortcut* and *Delete*:

[image]

If I choose *Delete* it disappears, but as soon as I refresh the view it's back. If I choose *Create shortcut* it fails with the message "Windows couldn't create the shortcut. Check to see whether the disk is full." A reboot hasn't removed it. This is Windows 10 Pro, version 1511 (OS build 10586.36).

Any ideas what this might be and how I can remove it?

Comment: What’s the shortcut’s target when you create one?

Comment: Explorer just enumerates all the drives and displays the list. There are other ways to enumerate the drives and display a list of them. Have you tried any of those? Might give a clue as to what that stray "thing" is.

Comment: @DanielB I should have mentioned, create shortcut doesn't work either. I've added that detail to the question now.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Can you explain what those other ways are?

Comment: Switch _View_ to _Details_ and select all properties/details to display. What is the _Type_ property then?